# Get multiple JSON values from search in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to loop thru json data looking for a keyword. Once found I need to pull 3 values to my console.log

This is for a Node.js project. The json is a local file.

How the data is laid out.

```
{
  "eventposdef": {
    "event": [
      {
        "$": {
          "name": "FIND THIS"
        },
        "pos": [
          {
            "$": {
              "a": "THIS VALUE 1",
              "x": "THIS VALUE 2",
              "z": "THIS VALUE 3"
            }
          },
        ]
}
```

Ive tried the following but it only returns the name.

```
// result is the entire file loaded. The below code does get part of the inquiry 

 var json = result;
    
        json.eventposdef.event.forEach(event => {
        if (event["$"].name === var2){
        console.log(event.name) //returns the name
        console.log(event.pos)  // returns nothing
                console.log(event.pos.a) //returns nothing
    }
})
```

I expect to return...

```
    "a" THIS VALUE 1
    "x" THIS VALUE 2
    "z" THIS VALUE 3
```

Comment: Have you tried printing your event to understand what you are getting? (i.e., `console.log(event)`)

Comment: @Alex yes I have. I have spent 10 hours printing to console trying different solutions.

Comment: @jabaa Sorry, I removed it.

Comment: Okay, I was only asking because you were really close! The only thing is that the data you wanted to print is nested inside the pos object, then inside an array, then inside a $ object. So you can access them like this: `console.log(event.pos[0].$.a)`. If the array can contain more than one element you can do: `event.pos.forEach(pos => {console.log(pos.$.a)});`

Comment: @Alex No no I appreciate the inquiry. Im teaching myself js for a Discord Bot project and am losing my mind lol. Im a VBA programmer from way back so I have a very basic understanding. But this is how we learn. I think I understand what you are saying. Because its nested it doesn't show with the main keys. You have to find those then call them afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to filter by event name or print all pos, but you can use Object.keys(pos.$) to get all the properties of an object and print them to the console. This is my reference code, I skipped null and undefined check conditions.

```js
const data = {
  "eventposdef": {
    "event": [
      {
        "$": {
          "name": "FIND THIS"
        },
        "pos": [
          {
            "$": {
              "a": "THIS VALUE 1",
              "x": "THIS VALUE 2",
              "z": "THIS VALUE 3"
            }
          },
        ]
}]}};

// Loop through the events
data.eventposdef.event.forEach(event => {
    // Check if the event name is the one we want
    if (event.$.name !== 'FIND THIS') {
        return;
    }

    event.pos.forEach(pos => {
        Object.keys(pos.$).forEach(key => {
            console.log(`"${key}" ${pos.$[key]}`);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! How can I edit it to only show the values of "a", "x" and "z"? Thanks again, you saved me big!

Comment: If there are numerous keys in pos and you only want to print the keys 'a', 'x', and 'z', you can modify the code as follows. First, define an array of keys that you want to print on the screen before iterating over the object. Then, filter out the keys that are not in the keys array.

Comment: I wish you were here to hug lol. I literally spent 12 hours on this to no avail. I was able to edit it and make it exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!